# Node http-server not working on Ubuntu linux

Tags: node.js, http, npm, httpserver

I am trying to run a simple http server in my project directory. All I need is GET request support, so I can GET html/css/js/etc.
For that I wanted to use http-server from npm.

I installed it with `npm install http-server -g`

Now I `cd` to my project folder where it has the index.html file, I open the terminal and run `http-server`

But when I open my browser at `http://localhost:8080/index.html` - it can't connect to the host.

Am I missing something?

Comment: From the npm: Starting http-server locally `node bin/http-server`.
Now you can visit http://localhost:8080 to view your server. https://www.npmjs.org/package/http-server ( "Usage" ).

Comment: Same result - can't connect. Does it store a log anywhere?

Comment: Doe you have output in the `REPL`? http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html

Comment: Weirdly enough it works on Windows for me but not on linux (Mint 17)

Comment: Cool. The REPL is basically a console of V8, http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/REPL/how-to-use-nodejs-repl.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Okay, the issue was - I had another package installed on Ubuntu, which is also called `node`

Node JS package is called `nodejs` on my system and I think that http-server is looking specifically for 'node'.
In order to work around this:

I removed the *node* package with `sudo apt-get remove node` and created a symlink for nodejs:

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node`

Answer (score 0):

First **install npm**.
Second **npm install http-server -g**.Next append after the **http-server** url template url like `http-server C:\xampp\htdocs\`

Comment: C drive in Ubuntu?